# Struts2 Checkboxlist values to display in Bold

Tags: java, struts2

I want to call list of property values in UI by using struts2 checkboxlist. I have one property like

```
A : for Apple
```

The property value I am fetching is from XML. I have written as:

```
&lt;b&gt;A&lt;/b&gt : for Apple.
```

I am seeing the below output in UI

```
<b>A</b> : for Apple
```

and I want string "A" in Bold.

I have checked that only s:property has escape attribute. Is there any similar attribute for checkboxlist?

Comment: There are a lot of attributes what do you mean by attribute.

Comment: I need any attribute which will work similar to escape attribute. Escape is not available for checkboxlist

Comment: How can you know that?

Answer (score 0):

If it's only the `<b>`-tag remove it in the action before displaying it. Otherwise generate your own checkboxlist with `<s:iterator>` and there you can use the `escapeHtml=false`-attribute.

```html
<s:iterator value="myvarlist">
    <legend><s:property value="name"/></legend>
    <input type="checkbox" name="myvar" value="<s:property value='value'>">
</s:iterator>
```